# Why there is a padding between image and border at the bottom?

Tags: css

I have an image inside a div, and I'm setting 1 pixel border to the div but there is a padding at the bottom between the border and the image. Can anyone please explain why?

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="border"><img src="example.png" /></div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#border {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I think it might be whitespace. Try <div id="border"><img src="example.png" /></img></div> as all one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `vertical-align:top` for image

Answer (score -1):

Browsers apply their default styles unless specified by your css, try explicitly setting padding in your css.

Firebug has a useful feature to let you see which styles have been applied to the elements on a page.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the image has both padding and margin set to 0, e.g.:

```
img{padding:0;margin:0}
```

Or, to change just that image, apply a class to that particular image and set the style for that class, e.g.

```
<img class="foo">

.foo {padding:0;margin:0}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are double closing your img tag:

You have

```
<div id="border"><img src="example.png" /></img></div>
```

Should be:

```
<div id="border"><img src="example.png" /></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. That's not the actual code. Just tried to make it simple... :))

Comment: @Levani: is it possible to set up  a fiddle here at jsfiddle.net maybe you have not cropped the image correctly